# Best way to handle .NET json [1,2,"three"]

Tags: .net, json

-edit- Maybe there is a solution by using attributes?

I found the weirdest json. It looks like the string below. The only way i can think of to handle it is to use an object array. I never seen ints and strings mixed in an array below.

I am then forced to typecast. Is there a better way to get the ints and string?

NOTE: The first array can have 0 to 20 elements. The array inside of it ALWAYS has 3 with the first two being ints and the 3rd a string. Maybe i can use this knowledge to my advantage?

```
{
 var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var o = ser.Deserialize<RootObj>(@"{""resources"": [[123,567,""<div ...""]]}");
 var o2 = o.resources[0];
 var v = (int)o2[1];
 var sz = (string)o2[2];
}
class RootObj {
 public object[][] resources;
}
```

Comment: Bad input, bad output. To my knowledge there is nothing you can do, except correcting the program/script generating the bad json (i.e. to use an array of objects instead of an array of arrays). On a side note: i hope you don't use such variable names in production.

Comment: dbemerlin: only for 5 lined functions ;). We cant correct it. It coming from a 3rd party and they put this into production, so i am stuck with it.

Comment: @dbemerlin: While not beautiful, the input is still valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore it because using an object is no bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bit of LINQ would come in handy here. Given your deserialised object `o`, you'd want something like the following.

```
var result = o.Select(c => new
                      {
                          v1 = (int)c[0],
                          v2 = (int)c[1],
                          sz = (string)c[2],
                      });
```

Note that the `new { ... }` construct creates an object of anoynomous type, you can use a struct if that's more suitable perhaps.

Still, you haven't given any real context, so the best solution may in fact be to do nothing and leave the deserialised result as a weakly-typed object array... You can always cast the values to specific types when you need to use them explicitly later.